# What is the difference between Handler (MessageQueue) and AsyncTask (SERIAL_EXECUTOR), performance wise?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-handler

There are a couple ways of getting data Asynchronously in your app. One is a `Handler` and another one is an `AsyncTask`. Now I've used both, and would like to know which one performs better/more efficiently at some tasks.

Thusfar, I've mostly used `AsyncTasks` in getting Webdata, and `Handler`'s in getting data from `Services` to `Activities`.

I would like to know if there is an advantage to using `Handler`'s for Webdata, or using AsyncTasks for refreshing UI from `Services`. What is the big difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`AsyncTask` uses a `Handler`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java), your comparison is... odd.

`AsyncTask` is great for transactional work: stuff that will take more than a few milliseconds and less than a few minutes. For that sort of work, if you have no need for your own thread management, `AsyncTask` is generally simpler to use.

If you have some particular characteristics that you need for your threading that `AsyncTask` will not readily handle, or if you need the thread for an indeterminate period of time (e.g., until the user presses a Stop button), use your own thread and something else to get work to the main application thread: a `Handler`, or `post()`, or `runOnUiThread()`. The "indeterminate period of time" recommendation assumes you are using one of the built-in thread pools -- I am never a fan of tying up a thread out of a thread pool that you didn't set up.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `AsyncTask` uses its own internal Handler. My testing is the "post" using a Handler is enqueued immediately. When used in `onCreate` this can be problematic as other actions must be enqueued after `onCreate` (haven't read through Android Activity etc source on this yet). So, trying to post to later load the layout did not work. Had to use an `AsyncTask`. Since `AsyncTask` has its own internal Handler; perhaps, then creating the task might occur in the queue directly after `onCreate` but the `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` might occur later as they are later in a queue.

So, `AsyncTask` worked better for this UI need to load an overly large layout file later with `setContentView` - later meaning after the `onCreate` so a `ProgressDialog` could be shown. `ProgressDialog` doesn't show up until `onCreate` is done.

Also, see this article for how to [choose when to use AsyncTask](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2011/05/difference-between-handler-and.html). Basically says when wanting to update UI. But actually you can do this with `runOnUIThread` so don't really need handler nor `AsyncTask` if you already know Java threading. `runOnUIThread` is like the invoke/invokeLater stuff in Swing.